# android tablet UI designing issue

Tags: android

I am new to android tablet development. I have few questions regarding resolutions that we need to target.

1. Which are common resolution that we need to target for Android Tablet?
2. under which folder do i need to put all images in project workspace?

Thanks,
Jim.

Comment: Have a look at [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and [Designing for Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html) from android guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tablets come in various sizes and screen densities
Two buckets which are important from size perspective.

```
layout-large 
layout-xlarge
```

You can also have layout specific to a screen size
e.g

```
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

Screen densities are either mdpi or hdpi but i have not seen many apps having different drawables depending on the screen size